# Why is the height of HTML and body elements initially equal to viewport but if content increases, then its height also increases?

Tags: html, css

If we don't specify its height explicitly, a normal block level element's height increases with the increase in the height of its content, **but is zero if its content has no height**

However, `html` and `body`'s height is **initially equal to the viewport** (approx) and it then increases as their content's height surpasses the viewport's height. Is this some special thing I need to remember for these two elements

[image]

Comment: No they aren't. The `html` and `body` elements are initially the height of their content, just like a `div`.

Comment: @Alohci Both of them show height in dev tools: https://ibb.co/dW3h9xR

Comment: That's because you haven't set a DOCTYPE. Add `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the start of the HTML.

Comment: @Alohci Thanks. Please put this as an answer so that I can accept it. I added the picture of my code in the question so that it makes for a proper answer